# No password Supplied, but no changes made

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I just opened an app I haven't worked on in a while to get back to work.  When I tried opening the app in the browser on my local machine, I get this error `PG::ConnectionBad (fe_sendauth: no password supplied):`.  I haven't messed with it lately, so I'm not sure what might have broken.  Here's my `database.yml` (just default rails created verbage)

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
development:
  <<: *default
  database: project2_development
```

Any ideas what might have broken?  Like I said, I haven't changed anything recently with this app, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly shows that `postgresql` the password you have not supplied, and after successful installation of `gem 'pg'`
perform the following,

1. `sudo -i -u postgres`
   you will be as a user of `postgres eg:- postgres@user >`
2. `psql`
   you will login in postgresql console
3. `alter user user_name with password 'new_password';`

   will change the password as provided
4. `\q`
   exit the psql console
5. change the `database.yml` as 
   `username: 'postgres`
   `password: 'new_password'`
6. `rake db:create`
   now try to create the database from rails

Should work !